# DB setup (use of 1 address table for multiple tables)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 1 `Address` table which has `id` as primary key (I know this is not the best way, but it is not relevant for the question).

I also have 3 other tables: `SUPPLIER`, `PERSON` and `CLIENT`. All of them also have an `id` as `PK`.

I want to use this 1 `Address` table in my 3 other tables. Simple by using the `Address.id` as a not nullable FK in my 3 other tables (business rules say a `SUPPLIER`, `PERSON` or `CLIENT` must always have an address so a null value is not allowed)

I can get this working easily...

But someone told me of a different approach:

Totally remove the FK out of `SUPPLIER`, `PERSON` and `CLIENT` and make a new table called `ADDRESS_REL` with columns:

- address_id (null not allowed)
- supplier_id (null allowed)
- person_id (null allowed)
- client_id (null allowed)

There are some pros and cons about the second method

Cons:

- When I have lets say 30 persons with the same adress I have 1 row in my `ADDRESS` table, 30 rows in my `PERSON` table and 30 rows in my `ADDRESS_REL` table. Plus these 30 rows in my `ADDRESS_REL` table also have 
  some empty columns (supplier_id & client_id)...
- When I introduce another database table, lets say `COMPANY`, and I want it to have an adress to, I have to extand the `ADDRESS_REL` table with column `company_id` (also introducing an extra empty column)
- I have to use database stored procedures to make sure a `SUPPLIER`, `PERSON` and `CLIENT` always have an `ADDRESS` (I can't do this in my program code because sometimes we hardcode data in the database and I want to make sure the business requirement of a `SUPPLIER`, `PERSON` and `CLIENT` to have an address always stands)

Pros:

- None

Can't actually think off a good reason, but I want to think this well over before I start implementing and possible building the new db structure. My question is to think with me, maybe I overlook something. I tend to use the first method for now unless people can persuade me otherwise with some new arguments...

Comment: what is your question ? if question regarding first mehod than i can say the first approch is correct with less effort and also performance and space consuming wise ...

Comment: Quite frankly: that "someone" suggested a crap solution - **don't do this!** Use the FK approach you had initially - that makes a lot more sense!

Comment: I prefer this "crap solution" time to time as it fits some cases. Like, I have some constant tables (rows are unlikely to be changed) and a transactional table (lots of CRUD). For example, a configuration table; So I  just create a relation table between several other "constant value carrying" tables and customize my applications' conguration via that configuration table... I 100% agree with marc_s in your scenario, I don't see any reason not to use FK's. Just do your first approach.

Comment: I would recommend not having one link table for everything that links to an address, have one link table for clientaddress another for personaddress and so on. Although in my experience link tables cause a pain in the butt with L2E / EF because of the lack of navigation properties and the joins required when querying.

Comment: The first approach it will be, thanks for the feedback all!